# ASCII Art, Issue with Code Blocks C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, ascii-art

I can't understand why the "\" doesn't appear when i run the program. I want to make some ASCII Art and "\" is basic for the picture i want to make.Is there any solution? I am using Code Blocks .

Answer (score 3):

With C++2011 you can use raw string literals, e.g.:

```
std::cout << R"(\)" << '\n';
```

The sequence `R"(` starts the string and `)"` ends the string. If the string `)"` needs to be embedded into the string, you can add some string between the `"` and the `(` which then needs to be repeated between the `)` and the `"` to end the string.

Of course, it may just be simpler to escape the escape character and to use `\\` as you already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 2 \ since the \ character is known as an escape key, like if you want to go to the next line you have to use \n and that lets C++ know that you want to move to the next line, so every time you use the \ character, you have to type it like \

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. You have to enter 2 times the "\" and then it will appear.

Comment: Yes please read [Escape Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).